# How to temporarily handle routing when migrating a rails app to react?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, routes

I'm getting ready to migrate a monolithic rails app to a react app with a rails backend and json api. For now we've integrated the react application as a static asset in our rails app, and are slowly transitioning every page to be rendered by react.

Problem is, that the react app doesn't do the routing (because the rails app handles it currently). Only when all pages have been transferred do we want to transition the frontend completely to react.

However, the react app shouldn't render the same content on every page of course. It should render the appropriate content, based on the page on which it is initiated (and it would reinitiate for every pageload, but the script for the app itself would remain the same).

So the question is, what would be the recommended way to enable react to render the appropriate content. Does it make sense to use react-router, and use it only to render the content based on the url, but not have it handle links?

Comment: Also, if this isn't a sensible migration strategy or there are better ways to handle this I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I'd use separate React component for separate pages for now. (Routing be done only with Rails.) When you're ready, you can move these exact components to the `Route`-s of `react-router` and make final transition in one step.

Comment: Yeah I'm already doing something like that. But it would be nice if all pages can be rendered by the same app (same js bundle), otherwise we'd have to have a separate bundle for every page. Which is why I was thinking of implementing a sort of routing to decide what to render where.

Comment: You can set up react routes that require a specific react view onEnter for instance–so if you go to that certain url, you can load the data you need in state and render that specific view (component). does that make sense?

Comment: @jakeaaron Yeah exactly, that's what I was thinking. I think I'd have to figure out how to make the router play nice with recognising the view it should load, but loading the required data with redux should be easy enough. And I can always cache the data in localstorage for the time being. Does that seem like a sensible (temporary) approach to you?

Comment: it's actually pretty easy once you know what you need to do! I'll give you an example

Comment: Hey guys, I am having trouble getting rails to handle all the routes, once I get to the react app, react takes over the routing, anyway I can prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your route file:

```
export default function(requirePlanData) {
    return (
        <Route path="/">
            <Route path="(:lang/)reading-plans" component={PlansView}>
            <Route path=":id(-:slug)" component={AboutPlanView} onEnter={requirePlanData} />
        </Route>

    )
}
```

Here you can see that on render of '/en/reading-plans/903' the 'AboutPlanView' component will be rendered, and the 'requirePlanData' function will be called to populate the app state required for the component view.

In your main js file with your requirePlanData you can do call your action creators for your API calls and populate state with your reducers before the view is loaded:

```
function requirePlanData(nextState, replace, callback) {
    const { params } = nextState
    var idNum = parseInt(params.id.toString().split("-")[0])
    const currentState = store.getState()
    if (currentState && currentState.plansDiscovery && currentState.plansDiscovery.plans && currentState.plansDiscovery.plans.id === idNum) {
        callback()
    } else if (idNum > 0) {
        store.dispatch(PlanDiscoveryActionCreators.readingplanInfo({ id: idNum, language_tag: window.__LOCALE__.planLocale }, store.getState().auth.isLoggedIn)).then((event) => {
           callback()
        }, (error) => {
           callback()
        })
    } else {
        callback()
    }
}
```

Now your action creators will return, fire off your reducer to populate state, and your component will be able to render with all the required data–based off of the url/route you defined.

Does this help you?

Comment: That's great! That's how I imagined it as well, but I had no idea whether this was a sensible approach. Thanks for the help!

Comment: no problem! I'm actually in the middle of the exact same process as you, and this is what we are doing! :)